# Open HttpResponseRedirect in a new tab, Django

Tags: python, django

Is there any way in Django I can redirect to a `URL` via `HttpResponseRedirect` in a new tab from django views.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

The url value is like `https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Reservoire/`

Comment: Not in the response, but in the `<a>`, you can do that with `<a href="some.url.com" target="_blank">`.

Answer (score 3):

Django, or even the HTTP specification does not provide a way to open a redirect in a new tab. You have, however, some other options.

You could send a response with a piece of javascript that opens the page in a new tab: `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Another way is using an `<a>` with `target="_blank"`